# SilverStripe: make a piece of HTML optional in page

Tags: silverstripe

I am not sure how to do this and cant find an example on the silverstripe site.

I want to make a checkbox in the CMS field list. When checked the page will display a code block I have. When not checked it will not.

In my page.ss I would have something like:

```
<% if $showPrintButton %>
    $showPrintButton
<% end_if %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the relevant code

```
private static $db = [
    'ShowPrintButton' => 'Boolean(1)'
];

private static $defaults = [
    'ShowPrintButton' => true
];

public function getCMSFields() {
    ...
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', CheckboxField::create('ShowPrintButton', 'Allow printing the page'));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! The only thing that I don't understand is that there is no class for ShowPrintButton. I though all things referenced in a ss by a $ variable had to be a class.. It looks like any database column can be a $ variable in an ss page correct? Or, does it also have to have a CMS field?

Comment: View variable in SS template is 1. a method on controller, with fallback to the dataobject. 2. a property on controller, with fallback to the dataobject. The method or property may return html text or another ViewableData object.